# How to sum value from database based on a column eg- sum of Salary based on department from a list with different department

Tags: c#, database, linq

How to sum value from database based on a column eg- sum of Salary based on department

```
Department Salary
A          10000
B          20000
A           
A          5000
C          2000
CA         10000
B          19000
```

Expected Output-

```
A          15000
```

I tried using LINQ but it sums up every value in salary column.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Table Column - [Department, Salary] [A 10000] [B 20000] [A -]
[A 5000] [C 2000] [CA 10000] [B 19000]

Comment: "I tried using LINQ but it sums up every value in salary column." - Hi Abbey. It really helps when asking questions if you show exactly what you tried. While you may think it is worthless since it didn't work it firstly gives us an idea of what you have tried and what you haven't but also means that we can focus on just commenting on whatever you were missing. Also given that using LINQ *should* work (if you use the right LINQ) it can be quite confusing to say "I tried using LINQ but it [didn't work]"! :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you table name is `DepartmentSalary`.

```
SELECT Department, SUM(Salary) AS Salary FROM DepartmentSalary GROUP BY Department;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Departments
            .GroupBy(l => l.Department )
            .Select(cl => new 
             {
                Department = cl.Key,
                SumSalary = cl.Sum(c => c.Salary),
             }).ToList();
```

This code gives you result like this:

```
**Department SumSalary**
A          15000
B          39000
C          2000
CA         10000
```

Comment: I'd personally do `Department = cl.Key` - `FirstOrDefault` feels a lot uglier and unnecessary given that it is the key for your grouping.